# clonedigger ignore file

Tags: python, django

How can I make clonedigger ignore a file?

I am running this command:

```
clonedigger --cpd-output src/apps/api/ -o ${basedir}/clonedigger.xml
```

But I need it to ignore tests.py file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clonedigger --ignore-dir=IGNORE_DIRS .
```

Or, use `clonedigger --file-list` and pass in a set of files that you *do* want to process. If necessary, you could use a UNIX tool like `find` coupled with `grep -v` to filter out files with names containing `test`.